# Integrated debugging pyspark dataframes sometimes outputs to Terminal instead of Debug Console

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, visual-studio-code

When debugging a pyspark program I put a break-point just After loading a dataframe (`ch`). Then, using the Debug Console single command line I do the following :

```
ch.count()  
32489
```

The count correctly displays under the `ch.count()`. However, If I try to show the dataframe contents I get the following :

```
ch.show()
None
```

Even so, the output of the dataframe did correctly show in the Terminal window! So if I click to view the Terminal window I see the output of the ch.show().
I've looked at other seemingly related questions but with no success. For example I tried the following without success.

```
"console": "None"
```

And :

```
"console": "integratedTerminal"
```

Also :

```
"debugOptions": ["RedirectOutput"]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`df.show` prints internally to `stdout` not `stderr`, if you want to print to stderr use `df.take` and print it yourself however you want. The None is what is returned by the `df.show` method.

Comment: ch.count() displays the correct count in the same window. Also, this use to work. I use to type ch.show() and saw the output without switching windows.

Comment: Is there a way to show both windows stacked vertically? That would be ok.